# htaccess Rewrite rule based on first two second two characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This should be fairly easy for all regex gurus, however we are having issues with it.

We made a mistake by allowing people to upload images to one folders. Now we are stuck with 150k jpg images in just one folder and its slowing our server a lot.

people are still allowed to upload to this very folder (live site) and we need to fix this slowly. the idea is to move files to subfolders like this:

`/jpg/121765_180x135.jpg`      to        `/jpg/12/17/121765_180x135.jpg`

first two/second two chars/file.jpg

the thing is that files with less than 4 chars should stay where they are

Comment: So what is it that you want to do? You want to rewrite the first URI to the second?

Comment: yes, thats what we are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

To rewrite `/jpg/121765_180x135.jpg` to `/jpg/12/17/121765_180x135.jpg`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?jpg/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.*)\.jpg$ /jpg/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
```

The other way around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?jpg/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\.jpg$ /jpg/$1.jpg [L]
```

These rules would either go in your vhost/server config, or an htaccess file in your document root.